# C# таблица EXCEL добавить данные с html

Tags: c#, html, excel, парсер

Добрый день дорогие друзья!
Есть задачка не большой сложности, хотелось бы реализовать красиво)
Хочу узнать, сталкивался ли кто нибудь с подобным и какие решения принимали!
Задача:
Есть таблица Excel с данными (код платежа, имя, организация и т.д.), так же есть html файл в котором тоже таблица (код платежа, номер UIN)
требуется Запустить программу,

- **Кнопка1:** выбрать таблицу excel,
- **Кнопка2:** Выбрать файл html,
- **Кнопка3:** Обработать данные,
- **Кнопка4:** Сохранить таблицу excel

Кнопочки говорят сами за себя, хотелось бы вообще БЕЗ вывода в datagridview и т.д., всякое может быть с данными(захочется потыкать там и внести исправления) делаю, для обработки данных нашей сотруднице, по просьбе конечно))

в результате программа должна сравнивать каждую строку столбца "КОД ПЛАТЕЖА" из excel с "КОД ПЛАТЕЖА" из html, в случае совпадения, из столбца "Номер UIN" из html, добавляется запись  в столбец который создастся в EXCEL "Номер UIN" и так по все таблице
мои сложности: не знаю как считать данные, сравнить и записать, а так же сохранить результат в EXCEL таблице

```
namespace EXCEL
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        DataSet result;

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog() { Filter = "Excel Workbook|*.xls", ValidateNames = true })
            {
                if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    FileStream fs = File.Open(ofd.FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
                    IExcelDataReader reader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateBinaryReader(fs);
                    reader.IsFirstRowAsColumnNames = true;
                    result = reader.AsDataSet();
                    comboBox1.Items.Clear();
                    foreach (DataTable dt in result.Tables)
                        comboBox1.Items.Add(dt.TableName);
                    reader.Close();

                }
            }
        }

        private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            dataGridView1.DataSource = result.Tables[comboBox1.SelectedIndex];
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Ваша библиотека Excel врядли стандартная, читайте мануал по вашей библиотеке.

Comment: Если html стандартный проще в VBA и разобрать, без шарпа и interop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для этой цели могут подойти 2 либы:

1. `EPPlus`- библиотека для работы с `Excel` без использования interop, что повышает производительность
2. `AngleSharp`- библиотека для парсинга `html`.

Грузите с помощью этих библиотек все в память и выполняете сравнение. Библиотеки достаточно популярны и интуитивно понятные.

Comment: В общем после бессонной ночи, пяти чашек кофе и почти пачки сигарет, я не получил должного результата..Собрал около 5 проектов, даже начал разбирать ужасный акцент представителей индии на "ютубе", но результата не получил..а вроде плевое дело..
Из минусов EPPlus не могу поставить, версии не сходятся, если все таки заливаю EXCEl? то сохранить не могу..Очень сердечно прошу, отпишите как открыть файл с ПК загрузить в память и выгрузить опять этот файл на ПК

Comment: Вот тут в самом топовом ответе показан типичный цикл работы http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34115343/update-existing-workbook-using-epplus-c-sharp Файлы должны иметь формат 2007 Excel

Comment: Все гениальное просто, собрал из того что было, lkz парсера HTML взял библиотеку CsQuery